# Undefined index Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on the access and permissions for users in my laravel project i want to display the function of the modules so i can add them to a certain role here is my database :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_modules', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');           
        $table->integer('rang');           
        $table->string('title');           
        $table->string('route');           
        $table->text('description');           
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('role_modules');
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_functions', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');           
        $table->integer('module_id')->unsigned();           
        $table->string('title');           
        $table->string('function');                
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('role_modules')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('role_functions');
}
```

and here is my models code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rolemodules extends Model
{
protected $table = 'role_modules';

public function func()

{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rolefunctions','module_id');
}
}
```

When i want to display the functions of each module in my view like this :

```
@foreach($rolemodules as $rolemodule)
   {{$rolemodule->func['title']}}
@endforeach
```

I get this error: Undefined index: title

Comment: You need eager loading of eloquent model objects.

Comment: what does that mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Rolemodules` has many `Rolefunctions`Change the code to:

```
@foreach ($rolemodules as $rolemodule)
    @foreach ($rolemodule->func as $func)
        {{ $func->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are returning the the collection back to the view you need to `load` the relationship like this:

```
$roleModel->load('func');
```

Then you can use it inside of your view like this:

```
@foreach($rolemodules as $rolemodule)
   @foreach($rolemodule->func as $obj)
      {{ $obj->title }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like the following:

```
@foreach($rolemodules as $rolemodule)
    {{$rolemodule->func->title}}
@endforeach
```