# Undefined index with Laravel

Tags: laravel

Getting "undefined index wars" on command and it was working before. But now when I run the command on a moved server it just errors out. I don't know if I'm missing an obvious answer or what.

```
    public function __construct(int $numWars = 500)
    {
        $client = new PWClient();
        $json = $client->getPage("http://game.com/api/wars/{$numWars}/?key=".env("API_KEY"));
        $decoded = \json_decode($json, true);
        $this->result = Collection::make($decoded["wars"]);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924794/undefined-index-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because the key `wars` doesn't exist on the response.

Most likely, the API you are querying has changed it's response format. You should check the documentation for it, and update your code.

Comment: Actually looking deeper, this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your $json is missing something:

Try this:

```
public function __construct(int $numWars = 500)
{
   $client = new PWClient();

   $key = env("API_KEY");
   $json = $client->getPage("http://game.com/api/wars/{$numWars}/?key={$key}");

   $decoded = json_decode($json, true);

   if(!empty($decoded['wars'])){
       $this->result = Collection::make($decoded["wars"]);
   }else{
       dump('decode variable does not have wars key or is empty:');
       dd($decoded);
   }

}
```